# Using nbgrader: formgrader page not found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbgrader

I have installed jupyter nbgrader by following steps from this link:

http://nbgrader.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/installation.html

After installation when I try to click on formgrader I get

error: 404 : Not Found You are requesting a page that does not exist!
Can anyone help me, how can i access this page?

Comment: Docker hub has multiple nbgrader entries such as https://hub.docker.com/r/conery/nbgrader - using such a docker file might ease your installation.